# Pra Que esse comando serve?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity-5

Olá estou com uma dúvida e preciso de um comando em C# que ative e desative um layer dentro do animator no unity 3d.
Esse comando server pra isso?

```
Animator.GetLayerName ("Nadando");
```

No caso quero selecionar o layer "Nadando".

Answer (score 1):

Esse comando retorna o nome de uma layer, e leva como parametro um `int`, ou seja

```
(retorna string) GetLayerName(int layerIndex);
```

Para o que pretendes o melhor será alterar o "weight" da layer:

`SetLayerWeight(int layerIndex, float weight);`

Também podes desativar a mesma com:

```
minhalayer.enabled = false;
```

Para saberes o id da layer podes usar:

```
(retorna int) GetLayerIndex(string layerName);
```

Recomendo uma leitura na [documentação](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.html) do Unity